# How can I create a stacked bar chart based on a timeline in R Plotly?

Tags: r, bar-chart, r-plotly, stacked-chart

Hello I am trying to build a stacked bar chart, with a timeline in the x-axis in R Plotly. The topic is about Non-Pharmeceutical-Internvetions (NPI's) in US States. The stringency of the interventions is on an ordinal scale. What I would like the graph to show is what stringency was in place in which time frame. This is my piece of code:

```
    for (i in restrictions){
  
US_State[[i]] <- as.factor(US_State[[i]])

fig <- plot_ly(data = US_State, 
        x = US_State$Date,
        y = US_State$RegionName,
        z = US_State[[i]],
        #mode="markers",
        type="bar",
        color= US_State[[i]],
        size=8)
  

  
fig <- fig %>%  layout(
    title = paste(i),
    yaxis = list(title = "State"),
    xaxis = list(title="Date"),
    barmode = "stack"
  )
  
print(fig)
```

What I get is unfortunately something like this:

[image: Seems like the stringecy or stacked on each other because they are not related to the date.]

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I cannot edit my question anymore. To be more precise, I have a dataframe which gives me the stringency of Covid19 policy interventions in US States on a daily basis. What the plot should do is plotting which stringency was in place at what time. Thanks! Actually the problem seems to be with the date - even though the date is of class date.